# How to call a bash script from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, bash

I am trying to call a bash script from a Typescript. Tried the following but didn't work, any suggestion?

```
var script = ##path to the .sh script##
console.log(script)
const { exec } = require("child_process")
exec (script)
```

[UPDATE]

IT seems like it's not calling the .sh script still, not echoing 'works'

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Did it fail to compile? Did you get an error message at runtime? Did your Node process succeed but your script failed to run? (Did you forget to invoke bash explicitly, such that child_process didn't know which actual executable to use?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed @types/node -> `npm i --save-dev @types/node`
If not you should install that first. Then try the following.

You can do it by adding the bash command before the script file path:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'

exec('bash path/to/script.sh', (err, stdout, stdrr) => {
  console.log(stdout)
})
```

or you should set execute permission to bash file with this command:

```
chmod a+x script.sh
```

and run it like so:

```
exec('./path/to/script.sh', (err, stdout, stdrr) => {
  console.log(stdout)
})
```